# How to make a 2D char array completely empty?

Tags: c

I am creating a 2D array using malloc and when I iterate through the array there are characters and symbols that I do not want in there. Shouldn't the array be completely empty?

I have tried to assign the null character to the beginning of each row but that doesn't change anything.

```
    char **structure;
    structure = malloc(sizeof *structure * 2);
    if (structure) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            structure[i] = malloc(sizeof *structure[i] * 20);
            structure[i][0] = '\0';
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            printf("%c ", structure[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

I expected the output to just be blank spaces but this is what appeared:

```
Z Ñ             P  Ñ             l   L O
Z Ñ               P  Ñ             N U M B
```

Comment: Please define "empty". That needs a definition. Are spaces "empty" elements of the array? Are null charactes empty elements of the array? Or does some int tells you how many elements are in use?

Comment: "*I expected the output to just be blank spaces*" Why?

Comment: Note: in the second loop the limit `i <= 2;` is incorrect and breaks the array bounds. It should be `i < 2;`

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty array or an empty `char`. You need to figure out which values you want to use.

Comment: If you remove the inner print loop, `printf("%s", structure[i]);` will work (print nothing) since the terminator makes each an empty string.

Comment: Other people have covered the main point, but be aware that what you've got above is *not* a 2D array - it's an array of pointers, a very different construct with very different use cases and advantages (mainly, it can be "jagged"). A 2D array in C is an array-of-arrays - can still be dynamically allocated, but not like this.

Comment: per the posted code, even when `malloc()` fails, this statement: `for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {` will always be executed.  Suggest, immediately after the call to `malloc()`  insert: `if( !structure ) { perror( "malloc for structure failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `calloc` function; this is what I often use. It does the same work as `malloc()` but it initializes all allocated bits with `0`.

[calloc documentation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.2)

Answer (score 3):

As you are accessing each character you must clear all position explicitly to get your desired output.

```
char **structure;
structure = (char**)malloc( (sizeof *structure) * 2 );
if (structure)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        // structure[i];
    structure[i] =(char *) malloc( sizeof *structure[i] * 20 );
    for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
        structure[i][j] = '\0';

    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ //you can not access position i==2
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", structure[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

You can also use printf("%s", structure[i]) to make it work with your current code. it will work because you have made first position of both strings NULL('\0').So printf function will terminate for both character arrays without printing anything. But remember, other position than the first one of both arrays will contain garbage value.

Comment: Your diagnotics and correction are valid. But your assumption about `printf("%c", 0)` is not. `printf` **will** output a null byte, and this null byte would appear in the file should the standard output be redirected to a file. The terminal may or may not show null bytes. For illustration purposes, `structure[i][j]` should be set to a visible character.

Answer (score 1):

When you are allocating memory the data inside the memory is undefined. the malloc function just giving you the memory. 
if you want the memory to be initialized to 0 you can always use the standard [calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) function. 
If you want to initialize it after allocation you can always use the [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) function. in your case

```
memset(structure, 0,  (sizeof *structure) * 2)
```

Comment: A better example would be `memset(structure[i], 0,  20);` or possibly `memset(structure[i], 0,  (sizeof(*structure[i]) * 20);`. The pointer array hardly need initializing.

Answer (score 1):

You are not really allocating a 2D array of `char`, but an array of 2 pointers to arrays of  20 `char`. It is much simpler to allocate a true 2D array:

```
// allocate a 2D array and initialize it to null bytes
char (*structure)[20] = calloc(sizeof(*structure), 2);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        printf("%02X ", structure[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```